What's wrong in my generated debug info in LLVM IR
Generated by compiler
I'm adding debug info to a go compiller (github.com/goplus/llgo) that used LLVM as backend, it passed in most cases, excludes a few simple cases likes below:
func FuncWithAllTypeParams(
    i8 int8,
) int {
    // Expected:
    //   all variables: i8
    //   i8: '\x01'
    println(
        i8,
    )
    // Expected:
    //   all variables: i8
    //   i8: '\x01'
    i8 = '\t'

    // Expected:
    //   i8: '\t'
    println(i8)
    return 1
}

It generates code:
; ModuleID = 'github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug'
source_filename = "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug"

@"github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init$guard" = global i1 false, align 1, !dbg !0

define i64 @"github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.FuncWithAllTypeParams"(i8 %0) !dbg !10 {
_llgo_0:
  %1 = alloca i8, align 1, !dbg !16
  store i8 %0, ptr %1, align 1, !dbg !16
  %2 = load i8, ptr %1, align 1, !dbg !16
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata ptr %1, metadata !17, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !18
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 %2, metadata !17, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !19
  %3 = sext i8 %2 to i64, !dbg !20
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintInt"(i64 %3), !dbg !20
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintByte"(i8 10), !dbg !20
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 9, metadata !17, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !21
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 9, metadata !17, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !22
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintInt"(i64 9), !dbg !23
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintByte"(i8 10), !dbg !23
  ret i64 1, !dbg !23
}

define void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init"() !dbg !24 {
_llgo_0:
  %0 = load i1, ptr @"github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init$guard", align 1, !dbg !27
  br i1 %0, label %_llgo_2, label %_llgo_1, !dbg !27

_llgo_1:                                          ; preds = %_llgo_0
  store i1 true, ptr @"github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init$guard", align 1, !dbg !27
  br label %_llgo_2, !dbg !27

_llgo_2:                                          ; preds = %_llgo_1, %_llgo_0
  ret void, !dbg !27
}

; Function Attrs: nocallback nofree nosync nounwind speculatable willreturn memory(none)
declare void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata, metadata, metadata) #0

; Function Attrs: nocallback nofree nosync nounwind speculatable willreturn memory(none)
declare void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata, metadata, metadata) #0

declare void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintInt"(i64)

declare void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintByte"(i8)

attributes #0 = { nocallback nofree nosync nounwind speculatable willreturn memory(none) }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!7, !8}
!llvm.ident = !{!9}
!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!2}

!0 = !DIGlobalVariableExpression(var: !1, expr: !DIExpression())
!1 = distinct !DIGlobalVariable(name: "init$guard", linkageName: "init$guard", scope: !2, file: !4, type: !5, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true, align: 64)
!2 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C, file: !3, producer: "LLGo", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 1, emissionKind: FullDebug)
!3 = !DIFile(filename: "debug", directory: "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug")
!4 = !DIFile(filename: "", directory: "")
!5 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, name: "*bool", baseType: !6, size: 64, align: 64, dwarfAddressSpace: 0)
!6 = !DIBasicType(name: "bool", size: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_boolean)
!7 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!8 = !{i32 7, !"Dwarf Version", i32 5}
!9 = !{!"LLGo Compiler"}
!10 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.FuncWithAllTypeParams", linkageName: "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.FuncWithAllTypeParams", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 4, type: !12, scopeLine: 6, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2)
!11 = !DIFile(filename: "in.go", directory: "/Users/lijie/source/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug/")
!12 = !DISubroutineType(types: !13)
!13 = !{!14, !15}
!14 = !DIBasicType(name: "int", size: 64, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!15 = !DIBasicType(name: "int8", size: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!16 = !DILocation(line: 6, column: 7, scope: !10)
!17 = !DILocalVariable(name: "i8", arg: 1, scope: !10, file: !11, line: 5, type: !15)
!18 = !DILocation(line: 5, column: 2, scope: !10)
!19 = !DILocation(line: 11, column: 3, scope: !10)
!20 = !DILocation(line: 10, column: 9, scope: !10)
!21 = !DILocation(line: 16, column: 2, scope: !10)
!22 = !DILocation(line: 20, column: 10, scope: !10)
!23 = !DILocation(line: 20, column: 9, scope: !10)
!24 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init", linkageName: "github.com/goplus/llgo/cl/_testdata/debug.init", scope: !4, file: !4, type: !25, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2)
!25 = !DISubroutineType(types: !26)
!26 = !{null}
!27 = !DILocation(line: 0, scope: !24)

At the breakpoint of the 3rd Expected positioin, it's still '\x01', not '\t'.
Setting breakpoint at ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:9

Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:7-9 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✓ Line 8, all variables: Pass
    Variables: i8
✓ Line 9, i8: Pass

Setting breakpoint at ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:15

Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:13-15 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✓ Line 14, all variables: Pass
    Variables: i8
✓ Line 15, i8: Pass

Setting breakpoint at ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:19

Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:18-19 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✗ Line 19, i8: Fail
    Expected: '\t'
    Actual: '\x01'

Without llvm.dbg.declare
If I removed the line that contains llvm.dbg.declare, at the breakpoint of the 1st Expected, the value can't read, and at the other breakpoints of Expected, the value always `\t'. Details:
define i64 @main.FuncWithAllTypeParams(i8 %0) !dbg !13 {
_llgo_0:
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 %0, metadata !19, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !20
  %1 = sext i8 %0 to i64, !dbg !21
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintInt"(i64 %1), !dbg !21
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintByte"(i8 10), !dbg !21
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 9, metadata !19, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !22
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 9, metadata !19, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !23
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintInt"(i64 9), !dbg !24
  call void @"github.com/goplus/llgo/internal/runtime.PrintByte"(i8 10), !dbg !24
  ret i64 1, !dbg !24
}

Tests result (verified by run lldb manually):
Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:7-9 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✓ Line 8, all variables: Pass
    Variables: i8
✗ Line 9, i8: Fail
    Expected: '\x01'
    Actual: <variable not available>

Setting breakpoint at ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:15

Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:13-15 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✓ Line 14, all variables: Pass
    Variables: i8
✗ Line 15, i8: Fail
    Expected: '\x01'
    Actual: '\t'

Setting breakpoint at ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:19

Test case: ./cl/_testdata/debug/in.go:18-19 in function 'main.FuncWithAllTypeParams'
✓ Line 19, i8: Pass

Compared to clang generated code
In a clang generated code from C, I can't find the difference, but it works fine.
int FuncWithAllTypeParams(
    int8_t i8
) {
    printf("%d\n",
        i8);
    
    i8 = 9;
    printf("%d\n", i8);
    
    return 1;
}

; ModuleID = 'main.c'
source_filename = "main.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128"
target triple = "arm64-apple-macosx14.0.0"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00", align 1, !dbg !0

; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind ssp uwtable(sync)
define i32 @FuncWithAllTypeParams(i8 noundef signext %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !17 {
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 %0, metadata !25, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !26
  %2 = sext i8 %0 to i32, !dbg !27
  %3 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef %2), !dbg !28
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8 9, metadata !25, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !26
  %4 = tail call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) @.str, i32 noundef 9), !dbg !29
  ret i32 1, !dbg !30
}

; Function Attrs: nofree nounwind
declare noundef i32 @printf(ptr nocapture noundef readonly, ...) local_unnamed_addr #1

; Function Attrs: nocallback nofree nosync nounwind readnone speculatable willreturn
declare void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata, metadata, metadata) #2

attributes #0 = { nofree nounwind ssp uwtable(sync) "frame-pointer"="non-leaf" "min-legal-vector-width"="0" "no-trapping-math"="true" "probe-stack"="__chkstk_darwin" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="apple-m1" "target-features"="+aes,+crc,+crypto,+dotprod,+fp-armv8,+fp16fml,+fullfp16,+lse,+neon,+ras,+rcpc,+rdm,+sha2,+sha3,+sm4,+v8.1a,+v8.2a,+v8.3a,+v8.4a,+v8.5a,+v8a,+zcm,+zcz" }
attributes #1 = { nofree nounwind "frame-pointer"="non-leaf" "no-trapping-math"="true" "probe-stack"="__chkstk_darwin" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="apple-m1" "target-features"="+aes,+crc,+crypto,+dotprod,+fp-armv8,+fp16fml,+fullfp16,+lse,+neon,+ras,+rcpc,+rdm,+sha2,+sha3,+sm4,+v8.1a,+v8.2a,+v8.3a,+v8.4a,+v8.5a,+v8a,+zcm,+zcz" }
attributes #2 = { nocallback nofree nosync nounwind readnone speculatable willreturn }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!7, !8, !9, !10, !11, !12, !13}
!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!14}
!llvm.ident = !{!16}

!0 = !DIGlobalVariableExpression(var: !1, expr: !DIExpression())
!1 = distinct !DIGlobalVariable(scope: null, file: !2, line: 11, type: !3, isLocal: true, isDefinition: true)
!2 = !DIFile(filename: "main.c", directory: "/Users/lijie/source/goplus/llgo/_bar/c")
!3 = !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_array_type, baseType: !4, size: 32, elements: !5)
!4 = !DIBasicType(name: "char", size: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_signed_char)
!5 = !{!6}
!6 = !DISubrange(count: 4)
!7 = !{i32 2, !"SDK Version", [2 x i32] [i32 14, i32 4]}
!8 = !{i32 7, !"Dwarf Version", i32 4}
!9 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!10 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!11 = !{i32 8, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!12 = !{i32 7, !"uwtable", i32 1}
!13 = !{i32 7, !"frame-pointer", i32 1}
!14 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !2, producer: "Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, globals: !15, splitDebugInlining: false, nameTableKind: None, sysroot: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk", sdk: "MacOSX.sdk")
!15 = !{!0}
!16 = !{!"Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)"}
!17 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "FuncWithAllTypeParams", scope: !2, file: !2, line: 8, type: !18, scopeLine: 10, flags: DIFlagPrototyped | DIFlagAllCallsDescribed, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !14, retainedNodes: !24)
!18 = !DISubroutineType(types: !19)
!19 = !{!20, !21}
!20 = !DIBasicType(name: "int", size: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
!21 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_typedef, name: "int8_t", file: !22, line: 30, baseType: !23)
!22 = !DIFile(filename: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_int8_t.h", directory: "")
!23 = !DIBasicType(name: "signed char", size: 8, encoding: DW_ATE_signed_char)
!24 = !{!25}
!25 = !DILocalVariable(name: "i8", arg: 1, scope: !17, file: !2, line: 9, type: !21)
!26 = !DILocation(line: 0, scope: !17)
!27 = !DILocation(line: 12, column: 9, scope: !17)
!28 = !DILocation(line: 11, column: 5, scope: !17)
!29 = !DILocation(line: 15, column: 5, scope: !17)
!30 = !DILocation(line: 17, column: 5, scope: !17)

I found some little difference about DILocation, but not affected the result when I change them.
How can I find the root cause?
UPDATE: add generated code and test result without lldb.dbg.declare.

Have you tried emitting only the calls to llvm.dbg.declare calls and NOT to llvm.dbg.value ? llvm.dbg.declare is used to specify that a source variable "lives" in a particular memory address (see https://godbolt.org/z/xPPdMPcr5). Optimizations, like mem2reg, may decide to promote that memory address to registers and declare the value that is assigned to that variable at every update point by using a series of llvm.dbg.value (see https://godbolt.org/z/heEz1cjzY), but removing also all calls to llvm.dbg.declare associated to that variable.

By the way, for the DICompileUnit, there is a DW_LANG_Go

@jmmartinez Thank you for your suggestion and cool links, I don't know this tool before. And I tried to remove lldb.dbg.declare, it works fine if not optimized (i8 = '\t' compiled to storeinstruction), but if optimization enabled,i8 = '\t'andprintln(i8)will be compiled to a constant and nostore` instruction here.

@jmmartinez DW_LANG_Go can't work in my lldb plugin currently, I will try it after this job finished.

Fix the comment above (can't edit it now), that is the result of removing llvm.dbg.value and just use llvm.dbg.declare. It just generate llvm.dbg.declare when the parameter type is pointer.

Exactly, after optimization the llvm.dbg.declare should be gone, the alloca (and all the memory accesses) should have been optimized, and the uses of the alloca should have been be replaced by the actual value stored in the alloca (in your case constants) and calls to llvm.dbg.value (with the constant for the first parameter).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
